# Wordpress: map existing page content instead of a copy

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a page with several subpages in wordpress. The page should display the same content as the second subpage. When I edit the page, there is an option to copy the content from the subpage into it, but then I would have to maintain two instances of the text. Is there a possibility to map existing page content into a page? I'm using Wordpress.com so I cannot edit any files/links on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a shortcode that fetches the content of a page specified. In `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'init', 'so20477735_init', 11 );
function so20477735_init()
{
    add_shortcode( 'duplicate_page', 'so20477735_shortcode_callback' );
}

function so20477735_shortcode_callback( $atts, $content = null )
{
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
         'page_id' => 0
    ), $atts ) );

    $page_data = get_page( $page_id );

    $return = '';

    if( ! is_null( $page_data ) )
        $return .= $page_data->post_content;

    return $return;
}
```

Example usage:

```
[duplicate_page page_id="12"]
```

**EDIT**

I missed the fact you're using wp.com. You should be able to do something similar with the display posts shortcode:

http://en.support.wordpress.com/display-posts-shortcode/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hints. Unfortunately I counld not get the job done with [display-posts ...], including the full content of another page is not among the options